# Swift: How do I get access to the navigationController in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, appdelegate, navigationcontroller

I have added a NavigationController in the StoryBoard and made it the initial viewController.
How do I get access to the NavigationController in the appDelegate.  Ctrl-drag from navigationController to AppDelegate does not create an outlet.

Comment: If it's your initial view controller you can access it through `self.window.rootViewController`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
```

Comment: Getting this SIGBART error : Could not cast value of type 'SwiftControlsTest.ViewController' (0x1006303f0) to 'UINavigationController' (0x101ecb670).

Comment: That's because you don't have a navigation controller set as the root view controller of your application. Your root view controller is a `SwiftControlsTest.ViewController`

Comment: `windows` is deprecated as of iOS 15. Also, you'll get an error if you try to do `self.window?.rootViewController` in `AppDelegate`; you can, however, do this in `SceneDelegate`.

Answer (score 2):

In custom functions use like this:

```
let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
```